# What is the word for "to furrow" in terms of eyebrows?

Tags: word-requests, phrase-requests

Trying to say "her eyebrows furrowed" but cannot find the right expression. I recall there being a similar expression (which warranted a different English translation), but can't remember what it was...

Comment: "furrow one's eyebrows"って"frown"とどう違うんでしょう・・同じようなもの？

Comment: @Chocolate According to some theories on [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frown), frowning can, but not necessarily must involve brows ("*frowns that incorporate the furrowing of the brow are a response to perceived obstacles to the achievement of goals, while frowns that involve movement of the cheeks reflect an unpleasant reaction*").

Comment: @macraf おおお・・ありがとうございます！＾＾

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add to 「[眉]{まゆ}をしかめる」「眉をひそめる」 given in the other answer, I think you could also use...

> [眉間]{みけん}にしわを[寄]{よ}せる

Answer (score 2):

The closest expression is probably:

> [眉{まゆ}を寄せる{よせる}](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E7%9C%89%E3%82%92%E5%AF%84%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B)
>
> 不快の念などから眉の寄ったような表情をすること。「眉根を寄せる」「眉をしかめる」「眉を顰める」「眉をひそめる」などとも表現する。

For example:

> 彼女は眉を寄せた。

Passive voice seems not to be very common though, unlike in English.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers, way back in some early 20th century novel (I don't remember exactly which one) I saw another expression. So if you want to go a bit more indirect and literary you could say

> [八]{はち}の[字]{じ}を[寄]{よ}せる
>
> 眉 (まゆ) を八の字にして眉間 (みけん) にしわを寄せる。顔をしかめる。「―・せて考え込む」 ([source](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/176935/meaning/m1u/))

This is meant figuratively that you arrange your brows in a way that looks like the sign for eight (八). If you want to make the opposite you could also say

> [逆]{ぎゃく}[八]{はち}の[字]{じ}を[寄]{よ}せる
>
> If somebody could clear me up whether its ぎゃくはち or さかはち, I'd be grateful.
>
> Edit: As pointed out in the comments, the 逆 is in relation to 八の字 as a complete expression and thus read as ぎゃく and not as さか.

As is stated [in the answer to this question here](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12130702332). I presume the answering person is a native speaker, but I personally have never seen that expression in novels.

Comment: `If somebody could clear me up whether its ぎゃくはち or さかはち...` --「ぎゃくはち」です・・というか「[逆]{ぎゃく}＋[八]{はち}の[字]{じ}」です（「[逆八]{ぎゃくはち}＋の＋[字]{じ}」じゃなくて）

Comment: あっ、そうですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the word you're looking for is 'to frown', 悩む